# Closures gone awry - why does anonymous function return last

Tags: javascript, closures

I was reading this article (#3) [on JS Closures](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/), and was trying to understand this point about closures going awry when the outer function's variable changes with a for loop...

```
        function celebIDCreator (theCelebs) {
            var i;
            var uniqueID = 100;
            for (i = 0; i < theCelebs.length; i++) {
                console.log("outer: " + i);

                //this anon function returns after the loop has finished
                theCelebs[i]["id"] = function () {
                    console.log("inner: " + i);
                    return uniqueID + i; //this is accessing the i declared in outer function, not in For loop...
                }
            }
            console.log("outside for loop: " + i);
            return theCelebs;
        }


        var celebs = [{name : "Stallone", id: 0}, {name : "Cruise", id : 0}, {name : "Willis", id : 0}];
        var create = celebIDCreator (celebs);
        var stalloneID = create[0];
```

Gives output:

```
outer: 0
outer: 1
outer: 2
outside for loop: 3 
inner: 3
```

I am confused as to why the inner anonymous function's output is console.logged last in line, and what this portion of the article is referring to? Where exactly is the outer variable being changed causing the issue?

Comment: `i++` is changing the variable. Notice that there is no new "inner" `i` variable, it's just the same outer variable accessed from inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point to understand is that a closure captures **the variable**, not the **current value**. Consider for example:

```
function f() {
    var i = 1;
    return [function() { return ++i; },
            function() { return i*2; }];
}
```

here the two closures are **sharing** the same variable `i`, so for you get this behavior:

```
x = f();
console.log(x[0]()); // ==> 2
console.log(x[1]()); // ==> 4
console.log(x[0]()); // ==> 3
console.log(x[1]()); // ==> 6
```

This means that if you simply create closures in a loop all of them are capturing the same variable and the value will be the one after exiting the loop.

The common solution is to use

```
return (function(i){return function(){return ++i;}})(i);
```

that is equivalent to

```
return (function(i2){return function(){return ++i2;}})(i);
```

in other words the closure is no more capturing the external `i` variable, but the `i2` parameter of the middle function (another variable that is created at each iteration). With this trick you are basically creating a closures that capture the *current value* of `i` and that won't be affected once `i` is mutated later.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the function

```
theCelebs[i]["id"] = function () {
 console.log("inner: " + i);
 return uniqueID + i; //this is accessing the i declared in outer function, not in For loop...
}
```

The value of `i` here inside of the function is referencing the lexical environment of `function celebIDCreator` and the variable environment of the anonymous `function(){`. As there is no definition inside of the variable environment, `i` must be taken from the lexical environment. Further, since the function is called at a later date, when `i` is taken from the lexical environment, it has been modified by the `for` loop and is now the final value (3).

Alternatives for this include using an IIFE to close over the `i` value.

```
theCelebs[i]["id"] = (function (i) {
 return function(){ 
  console.log("inner: " + i);
  return uniqueID + i; //this is now accessing the i declared in the IIFE
 }
})(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

It basically comes down to this:

A nested function has access to scope of the function that contains it.  In the example you posted the variable `i` is 3 in the parent function after the for loop.  The inner function is referencing the variable in the outer function.

In the second example in the article (using a IIFE) the nested function accepts the variable `i` as a parameter `j` to the function (IIFE).  In JavaScript numbers are passed by value so the inner function gets a copy of the current value of `i` not the reference to `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Closures store references to the outer function’s variables.

stalloneID.id  only store function but important factor is here that it has not executed yet.If you log you will see the below

```
console.log("inner: " + i);
return uniqueID + i; //this is accessing the i declared in
```

outer function, not in For loop...

So it has still able to reach current value of i.When you execute it(stalloneID.id()) because this function store "i" by reference,it takes the latest value of "i" which is 3

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that a closure (an inisde function ) access the value of i in outer function **by reference ,not by value**.

In this particular case, when the for loop ends and the function returns , the **updated value of i(3)** is used by closure  and hence 103 is returned.

We can solve this issue by using **Immediately Invoked Function Expression(IIFE)** like this:

```
for(i=0;i<theCelebs.length;i++)
{
    theCelebs[0].id=function(j) // j=i , passed on invocation
    {
        return function()
        {
            return uniqueId+j;//in each loop , correct value of j(i) is 
            //saved in array
        }
    }() // IIFE so that value is returned immediately 
}(i) // IIFE with current value of i as parameter to closure
```